# Django- IntegrityError at /tickets/new/ null value in column "payment_amount" violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, django

I am facing an Integrity Error in Django admin while trying to add data to the database.

The traceback is referring to a field that I added some time ago and then removed. I have migrated the database and deleted all of the entries in the database but I am still getting the error. I have searched for payment_amount in my environment and I cannot find any lines with it mentioned.

Could someone please help?

The traceback is as follows:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://3231d88fef004534aa79ab40a77c1898.vfs.cloud9.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/tickets/new/

Django Version: 1.11
Python Version: 3.6.9
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django_forms_bootstrap',
 'accounts',
 'tickets',
 'checkout']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/ubuntu/environment/issuetracker/foo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (null value in column "payment_amount" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (67, test, tsetes, 2020-12-28 11:59:48.049459+00, 2020-12-28 11:59:43+00, 0, , 0, , BUG, TO_DO, null).
) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/home/ubuntu/environment/issuetracker/foo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/ubuntu/environment/issuetracker/foo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/ubuntu/environment/issuetracker/foo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/ubuntu/environment/issuetracker/foo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ubuntu/environment/issuetracker/tickets/views.py" in create_or_edit_ticket
  55.             ticket = form.save()

File "/home/ubuntu/environment/issuetracker/foo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save
  451.             self.instance.save()

File "/home/ubuntu/environment/issuetracker/foo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  806.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "/home/ubuntu/environment/issuetracker/foo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  836.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "/home/ubuntu/environment/issuetracker/foo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  922.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "/home/ubuntu/environment/issuetracker/foo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  961.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "/home/ubuntu/environment/issuetracker/foo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ubuntu/environment/issuetracker/foo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  1060.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "/home/ubuntu/environment/issuetracker/foo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1099.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/ubuntu/environment/issuetracker/foo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  80.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "/home/ubuntu/environment/issuetracker/foo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/ubuntu/environment/issuetracker/foo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "/home/ubuntu/environment/issuetracker/foo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
  685.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "/home/ubuntu/environment/issuetracker/foo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /tickets/new/
Exception Value: null value in column "payment_amount" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (67, test, tsetes, 2020-12-28 11:59:48.049459+00, 2020-12-28 11:59:43+00, 0, , 0, , BUG, TO_DO, null).
```

models.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Ticket(models.Model):
    """
    Add a ticket
    """
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('BUG', 'Bug'),
        ('NEW_FEATURE', 'New feature')
    )
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('TO_DO', 'To do'),
        ('UNDER_REVIEW', 'Under Review'),
        ('DECLINED', 'Declined'),
        ('PLANNED', 'Planned'),
        ('IN_PROGRESS', 'In Progress'),
        ('COMPLETED', 'Completed')
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=225,blank=False)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    content = models.TextField()
    ticket_type = models.CharField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default='BUG', max_length=11)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=timezone.now)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    upvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="img", blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='TO_DO', max_length=12)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    
class TicketComment(models.Model):
    """Model that can create comments"""
    author = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    comment = models.TextField(blank=False)
    comment_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)    
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.author
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from tickets.models import Ticket, TicketComment

class TicketsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'ticket_type', 'image', 'published_date']
        
class TicketCommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Form for creating comments"""
    class Meta:
        model = TicketComment
        fields = ('comment', )
```

views.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Ticket
from .forms import TicketsForm, TicketCommentForm

def get_tickets(request):
    """
    Create a view that will return a list of tickets that were published and 
    render them to 'issuetrackertickets.html' template
    """
    tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now
    ())
    return render(request, "issuetrackertickets.html", {'tickets':tickets})

def ticket_detail(request,pk):
    """
    Create a view that will return a single ticket object based on the ticket id 
    and render it to the 'ticketdetail.html' template
    """
    print("ticket detail")
    ticket = get_object_or_404(Ticket,pk=pk) 
    ticket.views +=1
    ticket.save()
    # Display comments
    comments = ticket.ticketcomment_set.all().order_by('comment_date')
    # Form for adding a comment
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.get('submit'):
        comment_form = TicketCommentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            comment.author = request.user.username
            comment.ticket = ticket
            comment.save()
            return redirect(ticket_detail, pk=ticket.pk)
    # Form for upvoting tickets
    elif request.method == 'POST' and not request.POST.get('submit'):
        comment_form = TicketCommentForm()
    else:
        comment_form = TicketCommentForm()
    return render(request, 'ticketdetail.html', {'ticket': ticket, 'comments': comments, 'comment_form': comment_form})

@login_required
def create_or_edit_ticket(request, pk=None):
    """
    Create a view that allows us to create or edit a ticket depending if 
    the tickets id is null or not. 
    """
    ticket = get_object_or_404(Ticket, pk=pk) if pk else None
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TicketsForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=ticket)
        if form.is_valid():
            ticket = form.save()
            ticket.author = request.user.username
            return redirect(ticket_detail, ticket.pk)
    else:
        form = TicketsForm(instance=ticket)
    return render(request, "issuetrackerticketform.html", {'form':form})
    
def ticket_vote(request,pk):
    """
    Create a view that will increase the upvotes for the current ticket
    and render it to the 'ticketdetail.html' template
    """
    ticket = get_object_or_404(Ticket,pk=pk) 
    ticket.upvotes +=1
    ticket.save()
    return render(request, "ticketdetail.html", {'ticket':ticket})
    
def ticket_vote_list(request,pk):
    """
    Create a view that will increase the upvotes for the current ticket in the list
    and render it to the 'ticketdetail.html' template
    """
    ticket = get_object_or_404(Ticket,pk=pk) 
    ticket.upvotes +=1
    ticket.save()
    tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now
    ())
    return render(request, "issuetrackertickets.html", {'tickets':tickets})
```

ticketdetails.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load static from staticfiles %}
{% load bootstrap_tags %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="row">
            <h2> <i class="fa fa-list"></i> Issue Detail </h2>
            <hr>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 text-center">
                 {% if ticket.ticket_type == 'BUG' %}
                        <a href="{% url 'ticket_detail' ticket.id %}"><img src="/media/img/bug.jpg" class="img-circle" height=90px></a>
                    {% else %}
                        <a href="{% url 'ticket_detail' ticket.id %}"><img src="/media/img/new_feature.jpg" class="img-circle" height=90px></a>
                    {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-9">
                {% if ticket.status == 'UNDER_REVIEW' %}
                    <h4><span class="label label-default">Status: {{ ticket.status }}</span></h4>
                {% elif ticket.status == 'DECLINED' %}
                    <h4><span class="label label-danger">Status: {{ ticket.status }}</span></h4>
                {% elif ticket.status == 'PLANNED' %}
                    <h4><span class="label label-primary">Status: {{ ticket.status }}</span></h4>
                {% elif ticket.status == 'IN_PROGRESS' %}
                    <h4><span class="label label-info">Status: {{ ticket.status }}</span></h4>
                {% elif ticket.status == 'COMPLETED' %}
                    <h4><span class="label label-success">Status: {{ ticket.status }}</span></h4>
                {% else %}
                    <h4><span class="label label-warning">Status: {{ ticket.status }}</span></h4>
                {% endif %}
                <h3>{{ ticket.title }}
                    <a href="{% url 'ticket_vote' pk=ticket.pk %}" {{ ticket.upvote }}<p><span title="Click here to vote for this issue" class="badge upvote">{{ ticket.upvotes }} <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span></span></p></a>
                </h3>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-9">
                        <h5>{{ ticket.content }}</h5>
                        <h5><span class="boldtext">Ticket Type:</span> {{ ticket.ticket_type }} </h5>
                        {% if ticket.image %}
                            <div class="issue-img">
                                <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ ticket.image }}" class="image-to-zoom">
                            </div>
                        {% endif %}
                        <h6><span class="boldtext">Published on:</span> {{ ticket.published_date }} </h6>
                        <h6><span class="boldtext">Views:</span> {{ticket.views}}</h6>
                        <h6><span class="boldtext">Upvotes:</span> {{ ticket.upvotes }}</h6>
                        <p></p>
                        <a href="{% url 'get_tickets' %}" class="btn btn-default">Back to tickets</a>
                        <a href="{% url 'edit_ticket' ticket.id %}" class="btn btn-default">Edit ticket</a>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Ticket comments section -->
    <div class="container">
        <h4><u>Comments</u></h4>
        <hr>
        {% for comment in comments %}
            
            <p>{{ comment.comment }}</p>
            <small>{{ comment.author }} - {{ comment.comment_date|date:"M d 'y, G:i" }}</small>
            <hr>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <div class="container">
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %} 
            {{ comment_form|as_bootstrap_inline }}
            <div class="form-actions">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" name="submit" >
            </div>
        </form>   
    </div>
    {% else %}
    <i><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Sign in</a> to add a comment</i>
    {% endif %}
    
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Resize image on click with animation
        $('.image-to-zoom').on('click', function() {
            if ($(this).width() === 200) {
                $(this).animate({
                    width: "100%",
                    maxWidth: "90vw"
                }, 700);
            } else {
                $(this).animate({
                    width: "200px",
                }, 700);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

issuetrackerticketform.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="row">
        <h2><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Issues</h2>
        <hr>
        <form method="POST" class="col-md-12" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form | as_bootstrap }}
            <input class=" btn btn-success" name="submitticket" type="submit" value="Create Issue">
        </form>
    </div>    
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

[image: Integrity Error]

Comment: You are creating a new object (likely a `Ticket`, but without setting the `payment_amount`).

Comment: Share the model(s), view(s), and form(s) behind the `/tickets/new/` view.

Comment: I have updated the first post with those details.

Comment: You still have payment_amount column in your database table, this could be result of inconsistent migration history

Comment: Where do you see that?

Comment: Is there a way of resetting the database tables. I have deleted the existing migration files and run a migrate again but I am still getting the same problem.

Comment: I have also added an image of the integrity error. Can anyone see what the problem is?

Comment: I have solved this problem as can be seen in my answer, but created another problem!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem myself by running `python manage.py migrate your_app zero` deleting the migrations folder and migrating again.